# How to work with secrets in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, secret-key

In my code, I have API keys and other secrets directly for others to see.
I want to prevent that and put them in environment parameter (or hide them otherwise, if you have an idea)

How do I do that? I didn't really understand the answers when I googled it (maybe I looked in the wrong places?)

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Who are the "others"? Other people using Visual Studio? What kind of application are you talking about?

Comment: Ideally you want your server to have the API keys in environment variables, and then your code can hit a server endpoint, and let the server deal with how it manages the API call, and returns the correct data.

Comment: if you are developing with javascript, you can put your api-keys in .env files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Javascript

### 1. Add dotenv lib in your project (npm i dotenv or yarn add dotenv)

### 2. Import to your main file

```
require('dotenv').config();
or
import 'dotenv/config';
```

### 3. Put the variables in a file named ".env" in the root of your project.

Inside this .env file they have to be in the format: KEY=value

```
...
SECRET=123456abcdef
...
```

### 4. Then to use in your project, you can use: process.env.KEY

```
...
const token = sign({email: user.email},
      process.env.SECRET,
      {subject: user.id, expiresIn: 86400}
    );
...
```

### 5. 2. Add .env to .gitignore

```
//.gitignore
.env
```